# google chrome “managed by your organization” on linux

Tags: linux, rhel, security, chrome, malware

today I opened google chrome and saw this on customize and Control menu : "managed by your organization" , is that a malware sign ? if yes how can I completely remove that malware? my os is a Linux RHEL distributions and my chrome version is : 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]! **:-)** Is this a corporate PC?  What is mentioned in Chrome's `Help` - `About Google Chrome`? (Please [edit] your question and post screenshot using the image icon.)

Comment: https://mspoweruser.com/google-says-chrome-users-dont-need-to-be-worried-about-the-managed-by-your-organization-notification/

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That was what I was trying to see: corporate or not and then what exactly was going on...  (drop by in chat sometime so I can ping you there)  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google announced this is not a problem](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3595504?hl=en); if you add a domain account to the machine, [Chrome will now show this message](https://mspoweruser.com/google-says-chrome-users-dont-need-to-be-worried-about-the-managed-by-your-organization-notification/).

Many thanks to the esteemed [Rui F Ribero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138261/rui-f-ribeiro) who does waay too much for us here, and who provided the original link.